# Take the lid off a pot / a frying pan etc and put the lid on something

Tags: word-request, verbs

For a frying pan and a pot etc. I've always used the two verbs:

> - **take the lid off a pot, frying pan etc.**

and for covering them the verb:

> - **put the lid on something**

Recently, I found out that there are some even more important meanings for these two idioms, and just for keeping on the safe side, I opened this thread to make sure 
if these two are the most common verbs which you use in this case or not?

I have listed the other connotations of the two verbs below:

> - **To take the lid off something**: 
>     To keep something under control and stop it from increasing:
> - Example: We’ve got to keep a lid on our credit-card purchases.

and

> - **To put the lid on something**:
> - To keep something under control and stop it from increasing.

Therefore, I needed to make sure which verbs do you normally use for these two meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> **To take the lid off** something:
>   To keep something under control and stop it from increasing:  Example: We’ve got to **keep a lid on**
>   our credit-card purchases. and
>
> To put the lid on something:  To keep something under control and stop
>   it from increasing.

In your first example, you wrote "take the lid off" and then explained "keep a lid on". They mean opposite things. To figuratively "take the lid off" something is to uncover something hidden or secret. To figuratively "put (or keep) a (or the) lid on" something is to keep it secret or hidden.